# How to parse Json from Jquery that includes array in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, json

How to get array data from json in c#?

Here is the ajax code

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Weather/GetWeather",
            data: { "a": ["1,","2&"], "b" : 4 },
            success: onScc,
            error: onErr,
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

The ajax above will invoke method named GetWeather in Asp.net MVC.

```
    public string GetWeather()
    {
        //Request.QueryString.ToString()  --->  a%5b%5d=1%2c&a%5b%5d=2%26&b=4
        string a = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString.ToString());
        // string a ---> a=1,&a=2&&b=4
        .....
    }
```

what I got from .net is ----->    `a[]=1,&a[]=2&&b=4`

what I want to get is like ---->  `string[]a = ["1", "2&"]` and `int b = 4`. BTW, I don't want to define an object that includes a and b since these parameters are dynamic.

Comment: what is your data structure in .NET, and are you using the built-in json serialization?

Comment: 1. I didn't defined a data structure since the json data structure maybe dynamically changed. 2. I didn't use built-in json serialization.  I've taken a look at json.net, seems it doesn't fit for my purpose.

Comment: serializing a data structure is simple and you don't need external libraries, only thing is that you need to define a serializable class for your weather data and do this: `JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); string json = serializer.Serialize(weatherData);`. You can use JavaScriptSerializer as from .NET 3.5, it's in the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly.

Comment: Actually, I've done what you said in the project before. But as I mentioned, now the data structure is dynamic so that I cannot define a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `dynamic`

```
 dynamic lst = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>
               (@"{ ""a"": [""1"",""2""], ""b"" : 4}");
```

*reference System.Web.Extensions*

[image]

[image]

### edit

after looking , you are not sending JSON to .net !!!

```
var myObject = { "a": ["1,","2&"], "b" : 4 };

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

===> `'{"a":["1,","2&"],"b":4}'`
 you should send the STRING value rather then the  OBJECT which you did !

now youll have :

[image]

**change** :

```
  data: { "a": ["1,","2&"], "b" : 4 },

to

  data:{"myValue" : JSON.stringify({ "a": ["1,","2&"], "b" : 4 })},
```

and in c# read : `myValue`

Comment: @WouterH `How to **get array** data from json in c#`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried this way before I posted this question, the problem is that what I got from .net Request.QueryString includes special chars "[]" (this is generated by Jquery), pls refer to my example mentioned in the question. a[]=1,&a[]=2&&b=4. This cannot simplely Deserialize.

Comment: string queryStr = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString.ToString()); <*   queryStr here is a[]=1,&a[]=2&&b=4  *>
dynamic d = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(queryStr);  get error "Invalid JSON primitive: a."

Comment: A little bit confused, I will update the complete code in my thread. The JSON data I typed here is what I got from Jquery.Ajax.

Comment: @ley thats fine but you should not send an object but STRING which represent the object. feel free to keep asking me.

Comment: I have to say that you are really a nice guy! Thanks. Based on your comments, where/How I can pass the string rather than the object. I've no idea since it is done by JQuery.

Comment: Ok. look at me edit ... change `data: { "a": ["1,","2&"], "b" : 4 }` to  `data:{"myValue" : JSON.stringify({ "a": ["1,","2&"], "b" : 4 })},` and in the server side do `public string GetWeather()
    {
              string a = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["myValue"].ToString());
        
    }` and then do  `...serializer.Deserialize(a);`

Comment: Thanks man, I guess I got the point that I need pass string using JSON.stringify to the server. If that is the case, why Jquery ajax sends the literal object rather than string or it can convert the literal object to json string since we have already set the data type as JSON. It looks little bit strange.

Comment: @Ley lets make a distinction : if i want to send values or object and to touch them with c# - so fine. what you did was perfect. the problem is that JavaScriptSerializer / Deserializer wants a JSON object which is represented AS STRING !!!!!!!!!!!! one way to do it from client side is by JSON STRINGIFY.

Comment: @Ley look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191864.aspx it says there `The JSON *****string**** to deserialize.`

Comment: Understood. You do help me a lot. Thanks.